# google assistant sdk library and grpc getting error Quota exceeded for quota metric

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

working google assistant sample python applications i.e googlesamples-hotword and googlesamples-pushtotalk stopped after too many requests; and giving me an error as below

```
ERROR:root:Failed to register device: {
  "error": {
    "code": 429,
    "message": "Quota exceeded for quota metric 'embedded-assistant-prod/converse_requests' and limit 'ConverseRequestsPerDayPerProject' of service 'embeddedassistant.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:PROJECT_ID'.",
    "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
        "links": [
          {
            "description": "Google developer console API key",
            "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/project/PROJECT_ID/apiui/credential"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It started working again after quota renewed (after 24 hours).

I could not found any pricing information for google-assistant-sdk.

**Is there any way to increase the quota? to avoid this error?**

**What is the quota limit size?**

**It is currently in developer preview phase, when it will be released?**

**can google increase quota limit for specific project/user on request?**

Answer (score 0):

Developers can prototype with the API up to 500 queries/project/day.